# How to merge 2 cells vertically in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to merge 2 cells vertically in crystal report and then want to display avarage value. For more clarification I attached a image. Please help. Thanks in advance.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CluQl.png)

Comment: you need to get the average of only `GPA` column or all columns of the table

Comment: @Siva, only GPA column

Answer (score 1):

Its tricky. I can think of 3 options:

1) If you have some sort of common link between Paper 1 and 2 of a Subject, then you could possibly use Grouping.

2) Otherwise you will have to use Group by Formula and use Substring to match first few letters of the subject and if substring is a match then group them.
For eg: "English" for English 1st paper and English 2nd Paper to group all English papers.

3) Last and my recommended approach would be to work this out at backend at query level and return results grouped for Crystal to just dump on the report.

I cant replicate this in any of my reports unfortunately.Hope it gives you some direction. Thank you.